# Writing python script to batch add layers to multiple rasters?

Tags: arcpy, raster, layers, symbology

So I have looked at existing tools and there is nothing to batch change symbology to a myriad of raster surfaces (20+). Basically my manual process is to right click on the rasters layer properties, symbology, show classified and import my previously defined color table layer onto the raster.

Is there a arcpy snippet I can use to do this batch wise to 20 plus rasters?

This is using ArcGIS 10.2.2

Answer (score 2):

As Mr. Adam stated, you would use `arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(layer, symbology_layer)`. You are correct that a raster cannot be specified as the `symbology_layer`. A data layer that uses the raster as a data source must be reference. To do this, I would recommend saving the layer as a layer file on your local drive. Then, within your python script, call the layer file with its filepath.

See below:

```
import arcpy
symbology_layer = r"C:\symbology.lyr"
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")

for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
    arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(lyr,symbology_layer)
```